# Why are private constants stored in .NET assemblies?

Tags: .net, .net-assembly, il

Constants referenced by code are replaced by their actual values when being compiled to IL.

Since public constants can be referenced by code outside of a particular assembly, it makes sense that they are stored in the assembly's metadata.

But why are private constants stored there? There are no references to those constants in the IL of the code in the assembly that defined them, and they aren't exposed to be referenced outside of the assembly.

So what needs to access those values after the code has been compiled?

It seems to me that all constants in assemblies should be public, and private constants should be a language-level feature that simply cause the compiler to emit literal values.

Comment: Because of BindingFlags.NonPublic.  Being able to poke at the private parts is darn handy when you're in a bind and the programmer isn't picking up the phone to help you.

Comment: But what use does accessing that private constant serve? No IL references that constant. All that tells you is that someone decided to use a constant instead of hard-coding a value somewhere.

Comment: Well of course the "IL references that constant".  It is *embedded* in the IL.  If you never find a use for it then life is good.

Comment: I mean there is no difference in the IL between the code using a constant and the code using a literal. In other words, declaring (in C#) `private const string MYCONST = "Hello World"` and then doing `Console.WriteLine(MYCONST)` results in the same IL as doing `Console.WriteLine("Hello World")`.

Answer (score 4):

The C# compiler could optimize away *all kinds* of private stuff. Not just constants. It could remove unused members, classes, code. It could strip away private names. It could delete private properties and replace them with methods. etc.

**Reflection access and IL rewriting tools** come to mind as important use cases for private stuff. Also, debugging is easier when most meta-data is still present. For example, you can use Edit&Continue to use previously unused members. You can call statically unused members using the Immediate Window.

Maybe there are implications for PDB symbols as well although I cannot think of any right now.

Note, that .NET assemblies contain lots of meta-data that is *only* useful for reflection access. Attributes have no runtime implications at all other than being inspectable. Assemblies are meant to be rich and self-describing.

One could argue that constants are especially useless to keep because they are always statically unused. That, however does not mean that there are no reflection uses for them. They also can help with decompiling code. A smart decompiler could notice that a certain literal is identical to a constant declared nearby. Furthermore, why make an exception for constants to optimize them away? There are very few constants in typical programs. Even assuming that it would be better to remove them the investment would hardly pay off. Better develop useful language features in the same time.

Comment: Reflection can tell you that a constant was used, but that constant isn't referenced in any IL code. The compiler is already "optimizing away" the constant by injecting literals wherever it is referenced. Other private members can be accessed via reflection, so it makes sense that information about them be stored in the metadata. But all you get from constants is the knowledge that a programmer decided to use them. Attributes are public, and meant to be accessed programmatically to affect logic even if they don't do so on their own automatically.

Comment: Guessing that literals with matching values refer to the same constant is too error prone. For example, if I declare a constant `private const int SCHEMAVERSION = 1`, then a decompiler would map this code `var x = myarray[myarray.Length - 1]` to this `var x = myarray[myarray.Length - SCHEMAVERSION]`. And then there are cases where I might be referencing an external public constant, even though a local constant has the same value. If they had wanted to support that, I would have thought they would have had IL instruction support for constants, and then let the jitter inject the literals.

Comment: As far as the extra effort required to optimize them away, there really isn't any. If they had made IL constants public-only, then languages would have simply only added language-defined public constants to the metadata. The hard work is replacing all references to constants with literals, and that was mandated by the specification. It just seems strange to me that they would mandate something like that, and then not define constants to be public-only.