# How to access internal field 'NewLineConst' of System.Environment class (System.Private.CoreLib.dll) in .NET 7

Tags: c#, reflection

I want to access the following field using reflection:

Class is part of:

> System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e

[image]

I tried the following (amongst others), but the result is null:

```
 var fld = typeof(Environment).GetField("NewLineConst", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance); // => null
```

How can I access this internal const field which is part of the partial `Enviroment` class?

Comment: Why do you want that? Why not use `Environment.Newline` ? Trying to access a constant like that is no different that used a hard-coded \r\n` in code

Comment: BTW `partial` doesn't affect the type at all. It's just syntactic sugar for the compiler. I suspect there are two `Environment....` files, one for Windows and one for Linux that provide the `Environment.Newline` value

Comment: Cause I am curios how to access it, there is no special use case. Just can't access it and I don't know why, that's why I asked ;-)

Comment: First of all, [the source shows](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Environment.cs#LL172C54-L172C54) that the `NewLine` property does return the `NewLineConst` value. Second, [this SharpLabl example](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEBLANgHwAEAmARgFgAoQgZgAIS6BhOgbyrs7sgDsBnDA1IAGOgDkYAdwAy2HjCYR+ggLx0ARAB0omnuoDcHLrQYo6AWQAUASjZGuXRfwi4YAOgDqUbBhiWJMnIKSgLWhpQOAL5UkUA==) shows a constant is a static a field.  BUT during compilation, any reference is replaced by the actual

Comment: `BindingFlags.Instance` asks for instance fields, which constants are not. `BindingFlags.Static` will not reveal it either, though, because it's not part of the assembly. As to why not is unclear -- perhaps they're using a special build step or postprocessor to remove it. If you build an assembly yourself with an `internal const` field, it will still be emitted (as it should be, for reflection purposes), even if the value will be interpolated at use. Non-public constants can be removed with impunity without breaking any contract, even though the compiler does not do so by default.

Comment: Interestingly, ILSpy on `C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\7.0.2\System.Private.CoreLib.dll` shows no `NewLineConst` field. This explains why the constant is not visible to reflection---it's just not there. Is it possible that the compiler removes the constant as an optimization?

Comment: I didn't expect to see that `.field private static literal string NewLineConst` in the first place. Constants are *known* to be constants, which means they don't change. The compiler is free to simply use the actual value instead of a reference. That's why changing public constants is a breaking change that requires recompilation.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: True, but, so far, the compiler left them in, [presumably for reflection purposes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26811337/87698). Maybe the .NET BCL team uses a new compiler flag for that purpose or an explicit post-build optimization step, but that's just speculation.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: the compiler isn't merely *free* to do so but *required* to do so -- it may not emit a reference to the field. However, at the same time the constant field is normally still emitted, even if nothing refers to it. I imagine cutting down assembly size is something the runtime might be invested in more than other projects, so removing non-public constants may have been deemed a worthwhile enough optimization. There is as far as I know no documented way to make the C# compiler omit such fields by itself, though.

Comment: As far as I understood, is that it gets optimized away (literal) by the compiler, so it's not there during runtime and my reflection attempt fails. But my decompiler can recreate the const field again by using the assembly's metadata, right?

Comment: No, a decompiler only shows what is in the metadata, and this field isn't in the metadata to begin with. To sum up: the compiler never emits a reference to a constant, because it always takes the value and interpolates it as a literal, but it always emits fields, even if constant, for reflection purposes, and those fields are still there at runtime as well. It's just that this particular assembly has unused code removed after the build, and that would therefore also include all private and internal fields that are never referenced by code -- which automatically includes all constants.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't find the const, because it's no longer there in the compiled DLL. You can verify this yourself by opening `C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\7.0.2\System.Private.CoreLib.dll` in ILSpy.

In general, [the C# compiler **does** emit non-public constants](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26811337/87698), even though they are only useful for reflection purposes. System.Private.CoreLib.dll, however, is **trimmed** after the build process, removing unused IL code to reduce the file size.

Here is the relevant part from [System.Private.CoreLib.csproj](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/coreclr/System.Private.CoreLib/System.Private.CoreLib.csproj):

```
<ILLinkTrimAssembly>true</ILLinkTrimAssembly>
```

ILLink refers to the [trimming tool used by the .NET Core team](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/tree/main/src/tools/illink).

Comment: @Legends: it's probable that dotPeek is using the NuGet package to get at the source, instead of decompiling the assembly -- or maybe it's using a separate reference assembly. You can use `ildasm` (doesn't get more basic than that) to verify the constant is truly not there.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Sorry for deleting the comment. Yes, I see. Thanks for clarifying this topic.